# Netflix watch instantly doesn't stay fullscreen anymore

Tags: windows-7, silverlight, netflix

I've been using netflix on fullscreen on my secondary monitor, and the first time I used it, it asked if I wanted to stay in fullscreen when I switched applications, I said yes, and it worked like that.

I recently had [some computer problems...](https://superuser.com/questions/246048/macbook-pro-kernel-io-errors-freezes-extremely-slow-boot) and now it exits fullscreen when I switch to another window, to do work. Is there a way to re-enable this, to make it stay in fullscreen when I switch to another window?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactivated the device from account settings, and reactivated by playing a title.